# Denying access to multiple directories in vsftpd.conf

Tags: directory, configuration, vsftpd

I'm trying to use the **deny_file** directive to prevent users from accessing several directories inside a local root, using **vsftpd**.

For example, I would like to forbid users from entering inside the directories **admin** and **auth**, among other ones present in the **local_root** directory of one user.

If I write

```
deny_file=auth
```

It works, but only for that directory.

If I write two directives, like in

```
 deny_file=auth
 deny_file=admin
```

…only the second one seems to work, letting me thinking that the second directive overrides completely the first one.

According to the [**vsftpd.conf** man page](http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html#lbAG), I should use a command like:

```
deny_file={auth,admin}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work.

I also tried the following ones :

```
deny_file=auth,admin
deny_file=auth admin
```

Or using the regular expression syntax, like in:

```
deny_file=(auth|admin)
```

Without any better result.

**vsftpd** seems to accept denying only **one**, **exactly one** directory.

What is the exact syntax needed for denying *more than one* directory in **vsftpd**?

Should I include the regular expression into something?

Single or double quotes, slashes, brackets, etc?

If a simple list can be given, what is the separator if it is not a comma?